# mix redux-thunk with redux-observable

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-observable

I have an app using redux-thunk and want to try out redux-observable.
Currently I have a thunk action creator that does the following:

```js
const initState = () => {
    return dispatch => new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        //these each return axios promises as they get data from the server
        const pr1 = dispatch(processData1())
        const pr2 = dispatch(processData2())
        Promise.all([pr1,pr2])
            .then(r=>resolve(true))
            .catch(e=>reject(e))
        })
    }
}
```

and this is called from my component in componentDidMount like so:

```js
this.props.initState()
    .then(r=>this.setState({loaded:true}))
    .catch(e=>this.setState({loadError:true}))
```

Now I want to try redux-observable Can I combine it with redux-thunk and replace the `processData2()` call to instead dispatch an action which is dealt with by redux-observable?
i.e.

```js
const pr2 = dispatch({type:OBSERVABLE_PROCESSDATA2})
```

Now as far as I can tell, this isn't going to return a promise so the original code will now break as in `Promise.all` will `.then(r=>resolve(true))` immediately even though redux-observable epic has not yet processed it.
So is there a way I can wait for that dispatch to do the async stuff in the epic or do I need to basically go redux-observable all the way in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine redux-thunk and redux-observable in the same project.

actions ---> redux-thunk ---> redux-observable ---> store

But the idea of redux-observable is action$ in and action$ out. So you will need to write all your async logic in epics, and don't have access to the returned observable which is action stream.

So it's either you may want to convert the whole initState to an epic or just use rx.js directly in this thunk without creating epics